# pst-solides3d Installation/Use Isuues

Tags: pst-solides3d

first time user, having trouble getting `pst-solides3d` to work, hoping somebody has some easy advice.

I use TeXShop and my package is installed through MacTex. I've installed the `pst-solides3d` package but can't get any graphics to compile properly.

I'm trying to compile a simple example from the manual:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(3,3)
\psset{viewpoint=100 30 20,Decran=100}
\psSolid[object=cube,a=2,action=draw*,fillcolor=magenta!20]
\axesIIID[showOrigin=false](1,1,1)(3,2,2.5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The output of compilation is just a few math-style axes labels in apparently arbitrary locations (`y` and `z` overlap).  I'm not a very sophisticated LaTeX user so I'll just post the log output and hopefully you can explain to me in English what's going wrong and how to correct it.  The log file is the following:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex 2014.5.25)  18 DEC 2014 14:04
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
file:line:error style messages enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**3Dgraphics.tex
(./3Dgraphics.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/05/09 v2.6d package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
\XKV@depth=\count80
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/05/09 v2.6d key=value parser (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
\sa@internal=\count81

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalone' class)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option))
\c@part=\count82
\c@section=\count83
\c@subsection=\count84
\c@subsubsection=\count85
\c@paragraph=\count86
\c@subparagraph=\count87
\c@figure=\count88
\c@table=\count89
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102) 
(./pstricks.sty

Package: pstricks 2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
(/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count90
\pstFP@xia=\count91
\pstFP@xib=\count92
\pstFP@xfa=\count93
\pstFP@xfb=\count94
\pstFP@rega=\count95
\pstFP@regb=\count96
\pstFP@regs=\count97
\pstFP@times=\count98)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@xa=\dimen106
\pgf@xb=\dimen107
\pgf@xc=\dimen108
\pgf@y=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@yb=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\c@pgf@counta=\count99
\c@pgf@countb=\count100
\c@pgf@countc=\count101
\c@pgf@countd=\count102
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count103
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count104)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count105
\pgfmath@box=\box26
\pgfmath@toks=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks22)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count106))
\pgffor@iter=\dimen114
\pgffor@skip=\dimen115
\pgffor@stack=\toks23
\pgffor@toks=\toks24)
\psLoopIndex=\count107

`PSTricks' v2.60  <2014/10/25> (tvz)
\pst@dima=\dimen116
\pst@dimb=\dimen117
\pst@dimc=\dimen118
\pst@dimd=\dimen119
\pst@dimg=\dimen120
\pst@dimh=\dimen121
\pst@dimm=\dimen122
\pst@dimn=\dimen123
\pst@dimo=\dimen124
\pst@dimp=\dimen125
\pst@hbox=\box27
\pst@ibox=\box28
\pst@boxg=\box29
\pst@cnta=\count108
\pst@cntb=\count109
\pst@cntc=\count110
\pst@cntd=\count111
\pst@cntg=\count112
\pst@cnth=\count113
\pst@cntm=\count114
\pst@cntn=\count115
\pst@cnto=\count116
\pst@cntp=\count117
\@zero=\count118
\pst@toks=\toks25
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
\psunit=\dimen126
\psxunit=\dimen127
\psyunit=\dimen128
\pst@C@@rType=\count119
\pslinewidth=\dimen129
\psk@startLW=\dimen130
\psk@endLW=\dimen131
\pst@customdefs=\toks26
\pslinearc=\dimen132
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen133
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen134
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen135
\everypsbox=\toks27
\psframesep=\dimen136
\pslabelsep=\dimen137
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen138
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen139
\pst@shift=\dimen140
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx)))
File: pstricks.tex 2014/10/25 v2.60 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
File: pst-fp.tex 2014/10/25 v2.60 `PST-fp' (hv)

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2014/04/28 v4.01 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK))
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.))
\sa@box=\box30)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d.sty
Package: pst-solides3d 2009/07/25 package wrapper for pst-solides3d

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex
v1.33, 2014/03/25
\psrow=\count120
\pscol=\count121
\psmatrixcnt=\count122
\psrowsep=\skip43
\pscolsep=\skip44
\pst@args=\count123
\num@pts=\count124
\pst@argcnt=\count125)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/multido/multido.tex
v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>
\multido@count=\count126
\multidocount=\count127
\multido@stuff=\toks28) 
`PSTSOLIDESIIID' v4.25, 2014/03/22
\test@mode=\count128
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 987 replaced by U+FFFD.)
File: pst-solides3d.tex 2014/03/22 v4.25 `PST-solides3D')
(./3Dgraphics.aux)
\openout1 = `3Dgraphics.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 8.
[1] (./3Dgraphics.aux))

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
8624 strings out of 493734
155971 string characters out of 6146348
241927 words of memory out of 5000000
11894 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
43i,5n,56p,619b,254s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on 3Dgraphics.pdf (1 page).
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is *specific* to XeLaTeX, since a compilation with LaTeX > DVIps > PS2PDF works as expected. By the way, the code comes from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/doc/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf) (section **2.4. The axes in 3d**, p 18).

Comment: Thank you! `latex  name.tex` produces a dvi, and `dvips name.dvi` produces a ps, but I can't run ps2pdf on the ps file.  Get the following error:

Comment: `Error: /undefined in book
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval-- nostringval--        --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--  nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1900   1   3   %oparray_pop   1899   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   1771   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--`

Comment: `Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1168/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Invalid argument
Current file position is 3587
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`

Comment: It works fine here. However, I have a later version of Ghostscript (9.15), so perhaps that makes a difference?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I've updated ghostscript, still receiving the same error message.  Does anybody know how to interpret that error message?

Comment: Probably need a -dNOSAFER...